# docker: quickstart cloudera hue configuration issue

Tags: docker, hadoop, hive, cloudera, hue

I am using **Docker toolbox**, the image is: **cloudera/quickstart**.

Due to my computer, the docker run on 4GB memory and 2 cpu.

when i create new container the **hue** and **hive** works well, but when i use the container again (after exit) i get many problems in the **hue** therefore the **hive** is not working.

for example one of the errors:
[the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8vLG.jpg)

the code i use to create new container:

```
docker run --hostname=quickstart.cloudera --privileged=true -t -i --publish-all=true -p 8888:8888 -p 80:80 --name cloudera-test cloudera/quickstart /usr/bin/docker-quickstart
```

so this is a problem of porting or hardware or something else?

Comment: In general, I think the docker quickstart needs maybe 6GB to actually run... It starts much more than Hadoop, Hue, and Hive... If those are the only compenents you want, I have a Docker setup here (replace Hive with Spark) https://github.com/cricket007/docker-stacks/tree/master/hadoop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i got the answer,
because my computer have 8 GiB memmory, when i use the command

```
docker start [container name]
```

it takes time to all the services to startup
we can see the status of all the services with the command

```
service --status-all
```

the location of all the services is: /etc/init.d/
so i suggest not to try get in the hue immediately after the container is startup.
if still there is problems try to check whice service is not OK.
for the HBase services we need to shut down them in this order:
1)  service hbase-thrift stop
2)  service hbase-regionserver stop
3)  service hbase-master stop
and to start from bottom to up (3, 2, 1)
for more details you can read [here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-7-x/topics/cdh_ig_services_stop.html)